# DRF and TensorFlow in Production WSGI. How to load models only once for all requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, tensorflow, django-rest-framework

I've created an API using the **Django Rest Framework**. The API uses a model for object classification using TensorFlow. The initial load of TensorFlow (`import tensorflow as tf`) can take time to instantiate *(around 30 seconds)*, thankfully I only need them once and then the rest of my application can make use of accessing the pre-loaded model.

Locally, I solved this issue by importing TensorFlow and my models just once during Django's start-up in **settings.py**, for example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
MODEL = tf.keras.models.load_model(BASE_DIR /'saved_model/')
```

This allows me to call and reuse the model in my views/serializers without having to re-import or load them on every request again, for example:

In serializers.py:

```
# Get Model
model = settings.MODEL
model.predict(SOMEPADDEDVALUE)
```

Everything works well in my local development *(using `runserver`)*. However, I would like to move my Django API to production and I'm worried about the above approach!

I will be using a **WSGI server** which I believe will use **Multi-Threading** *(or **multiprocess** I get these confused)* and the initial loading of my models will be duplicated on every request *(I think)* meaning the API will be unusable.

I'm sure I'm not the first to come across this issue using TensorFlow saved models with Django in Production, but I'm struggling to find anything that helps explain how one goes about it. How do others solve this issue?

**To be clear: Question:**

Using Django in production (WSGI)... How do I load my models **just once** *(like a singleton)* and make them available on every request without loading them again in production?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just load the model in each process, as happens naturally.  You'll have the same data in each worker, and unless you want to re-load the data there is no harm in that.  Workers don't die after processing a request, they just serve the next one.

Comment: The main reason is the amount of time it takes Tensorflow to initial load. The very first import takes around 10 seconds.